# Test with different SQL Server 2008 collations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

Currently I am creating a T-SQL script to verify data in a certain database. This script is validating a lot of `NVARCHAR` columns to detect data problems.

Because this script must be run on more than 1000 databases, I encountered problems with collation setting of the different servers and attached databases.

I was not able to change the collation of my database and server on my development pc to test this before run the script on the machines in the production environment.

- Is it correct the server and database collation cannot be changed?
- Is there a workaround to change server or database collation?

If this is possible or there is another way to test, it will save me time to test the huge script I have created.

**EDIT**: I was not clear about the goal:
I need to make the collations equal in the query. I can do this by running the script on all machines in the production environment. If the query causes problems, I can go to the error and add the COLLATION clause. I want to test this on my development machine instead of start testing this part of the script on a customers environment.

Answer (score 1):

For safety I would explicitly make collations equal in the queries using COLLATE clause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

Comment: Thats correct but I need to test the query to know where to make the collations equal. Do you have suggestions to verify a 5000 lines of sql to know where to set the collation?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can change those:

- [Setting and changing the Server Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx)
- [Setting and changing the database collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx)

But be aware: changing a collation (both server or database) **does not** change the collation on the columns that are already present in your database!

If you need to do this, you need to change every relevant column, in every table of all your databases.